# onClickListener for ImageView within ListView managed by ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have an `ListView` where the content is handled by a custom `ArrayAdapter`. The layout I'm using has one `TextView` and one `ImageView`.

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/string"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/default"
        android:textSize="20sp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/delete_row"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/delete_row"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Java Class:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new StringList(this, strings);
listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Now I declare a `onClickListener` for the hole item, which is quite easy:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
....
});
```

But know I also want to have an `onClickListener` for the `ImageView` and

**I don't want to put the `onClickListener` in the custom `ArrayAdapter` file, because when clicking on the image, there should happen a lot of things (not only removing the row).**

So how can I set an `onClickListener` to the `ImageView` within the `ListView`, managed by the `ArrayAdapter`?

Comment: `I don't want to put the onClickListener in the custom ArrayAdapter file` then create a listener which pass click event to class when ImageView Click in `Adapter` . something link eventbus

Comment: You have onClickListener on the adapter and when the imageview is clicked,you call a method on the activity with other implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> I also want to have an onClickListener for the ImageView

This we can't achieve in `onClickListener`

> I don't want to put the onClickListener in the custom ArrayAdapter
>   file

We can get ImageView click listener only in Adapter

> when clicking on the image, there should happen a lot of things (not
>   only removing the row)

This we can achieve through interface in Adapterview

**How..?**

Create one interface in you adapter like this.

```
public interface OnAdapterItemClickListener {
    public void onClickImage(String value, int position);
    public void onViewClicked(String value, int position);
}
```

Implement this interface in your activity.

Then add this listener in your adapter constructor, like this,

```
public StringList(this, ArrayList<String> strings, OnAdapterItemClickListener onAdapterItemClickListener) {
    mOnAdapterItemClickListener = onAdapterItemClickListener;

    //.. Your code here
}
```

Add the click listener in your `getView` like this,

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Your code here

    final String value = mStrings.get(position);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mOnAdapterItemClickListener.onImageClicked(value, position);
        }
    });

    convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mOnAdapterItemClickListener.onViewClicked(value, position);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

finally, in your activity, you will get the callback like this, which you already implemented.

```
@Override
public void onImageClicked(String value, int position) {
    // Your actions for Image
}

@Override
public void onViewClicked(String value, int position) {
  // Your actions for view click
}
```

Hope this will help you. If you have any query let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the adapter getView implement OnClickListener for image view

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
    }

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           // do your staff
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question: I don't want to put the `onClickListener`  in the custom `ArrayAdapter` file, because when clicking on the image, there should happen a lot of things

Answer (score 0):

In adapter class set ImageView final and the set onclicklistner to that imageview. like

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);

imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       //your code
    }
});
```

Comment: As I wrote in my question: I don't want to put the `onClickListener`  in the custom `ArrayAdapter` file, because when clicking on the image, there should happen a lot of things

Comment: can you explain what happen when you use onClickListner in custom ArrayAdapter

Comment: At least I can't do things easily like remove the string from an string array when it's removed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to jst click event to ImageView;

```
 ImageView iv= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv);

iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       // do your operation

    }
});
```

You can also use listview.setOnItemClickListener like below code;

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long viewId) {

            ImageView iv= (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);

          iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
   // do your operation

  }
 });


 }
  });
```

Comment: Should I put this within the Adapter class or within the main class?

Comment: implement in adapter class after define ImageView

Comment: As I wrote in my question: I don't want to put the `onClickListener`  in the custom `ArrayAdapter` file, because when clicking on the image, there should happen a lot of things

Comment: If user will click on item layout (not on image), event will be processed in image's click listener. I think this is not desired behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `StringList` is you own adapter implementation, just add listener methods to registrate custom `OnImageClickListener` for images:

```
public class ListenableStringList extends StringList {

    private final int imageId;

    // if listener is not registered via setOnImageClickListener, use do-nothing implementation...
    private OnImageClickListener imageClickListener = new OnImageClickListener() {
        @Override public void onImageClick(ImageView v, int position) {/*do-nothing*/}
    };

    public ListenableStringList(..., int imageId) {
        super(...);
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }        

    public void setOnImageClickListener(OnClickListener imageClickListener) {
        this.imageClickListener  = imageClickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        final ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(imageId);
        image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override void onClick(View v) {
                // delegate event to your custom listener
                imageClickListener.onImageClick(image, position);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    public interface OnImageClickListener {
         void onImageClick(ImageView v, int position);
    }
}
```

In your activity/fragment:

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
ListenableStringList adapter = new ListenableStringList(this, strings, R.id.image);
adapter.setOnImageClickListener(new OnImageClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onImageClick(ImageView v, int position) {
        // handle click event...
    }
});
listView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty));
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: How do I get the position of the list item, the image was clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

ok i did not tried in arayadapter but , this is what I did in recyclerview , you may get an idea

```
1 I created an interface like below

public interface Yourinterface {
public void yourmethodname(int position, int id, String anyvalue);
}


2 ,in onBindViewHolder (inside Recycler adapter)

Yourinterface yourinterface;

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final Viewholder holder, final int position) {

    final Group group = GroupList.get(position);


        holder.imgview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                yourinterface.yourmethodname(position, data.get_id(), data.getdataName());
            }
        });


}


3, At last in Activity

class extends Activity{

Yourinterface yourinterface;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_activity_addmember_list);

    Adapter adapter=new Addmember_group_list_adapter(this,yourinterface,GroupList);
    GrpList_recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    yourinterface=new Yourinterface() {

        @Override
        public void youmethod(int position, int id, String value) {
         // DO ANYTHING HERE    
        }
    };

}
```